# How to set and access later to another entity's property from an entity in Unity ECS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-dots, unity-ecs

I am trying to make a simple AI logic that has 3 states; `Idle`, `Chase`, `Attack`. In `Idle` state human entities should set their targets, in `Chase` state they will chase and ultimately `Attack`. I made it but with searching within double `foreach` loop and it isn't performant.

So I decided to hold a cache of all human's id's and `LocalTransform`s and set the target id to the targeter. This way I wanted to be able to get the target position with just `positions[targetIndex]`.

1. If I store the `LocalTransform`s in a `BlobArray` and set a target index for the target's `LocalTransform` into the targeter's property, `LocalTransform`s simply don't updating because they are being set only at the initialization when I assign the `LocalTransform`s.
2. I tried to update the `LocalTransform` `BlobArray` in a job struct but simple I can't pass a `BlobArray` into the job struct (it says `"InvalidOperationException: HumanFindTargetJob.JobData.arrayAspect.Value._Data uses unsafe Pointers which is not allowed."`) and I don't want to make it on the main thread.
3. I tried to do the things with `SystemAPI.Query` but I can't get a reference and send the query to the job and to get the query I must do it in a system.
4. I tried to hold the properties in separate `NativeArray`s in a singleton centralized c# class but it is not compatible with the Burst complier.

Can you help me?

Comment: you can pass in native arrays, which you populate

Comment: `BlobArray` is designed for data that never changes - like meshes, animations or textures etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate `IComponentData` to hold distinct data, for example:

```
public struct HumanState : IComponentData
{
    public EHumanState Value;
}

public struct HumanTarget : IComponentData
{
    public Entity Value;
}

// etc.
```

then, to access target's position you can use `GetComponentLookup<LocalTransform>`:

```cs
[BurstCompile]
public void OnUpdate ( ref SystemState state )
{
    var transformData = SystemAPI.GetComponentLookup<LocalTransform>( isReadOnly:true );
            
    foreach( var (humanState,humanTarget,transform) in SystemAPI.Query<HumanState,HumanTarget,LocalTransform>() )
    {
        if( humanState.Value==EHumanState.Chasing )
        if( transformData.TryGetComponent(humanTarget.Value,out var targetTransform) )
        {
            float3 targetPos = targetTransform.Position;
            /* moves toward target position */
        }
    }
}
```